# ValidationError - Django Q Query - is not a valid UUID

Tags: django

I am trying to get a value from the User Model, my requirement is that `or` condition should be in same query.

```
User.objects.get(
    Q(premium_referral=form.cleaned_data.get('referral_code')) | 
    Q(id=form.cleaned_data.get('referral_code'))
)
```

But it gives an error:

```
ValidationError at /register
['“XUSB5” is not a valid UUID.']
```

The above query works perfect for `id` but not for `premium_referral` field. If I pass a UUID, it works, but if I pass 5 char `premium_referral`, then it fails.

Query also works perfectly when I separate them:

```
User.objects.get(premium_referral=form.cleaned_data.get('referral_code'))
User.objects.get(id=form.cleaned_data.get('referral_code'))
```

Below is the model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    premium_referral = models.CharField(('Premium Referral Code'), max_length=30, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
```

Traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /register
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2434, in to_python
    return uuid.UUID(**{input_form: value})
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/uuid.py", line 171, in __init__
    raise ValueError('badly formed hexadecimal UUID string')
ValueError: badly formed hexadecimal UUID string

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "apps/accounts/views.py", line 31, in register
    referrer = User.objects.get(
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 424, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 941, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 961, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 968, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1393, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1412, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1265, in build_filter
    return self._add_q(
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1412, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1347, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1193, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 77, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2418, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2436, in to_python
    raise exceptions.ValidationError(
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“XUSB5” is not a valid UUID.']
[19/Nov/2021 09:52:54] "POST /register HTTP/1.1" 500 154403
```

Comment: Where exactly is the error being raised, can you post the full traceback?

Comment: @IainShelvington Please check i added

Comment: Why are you filtering `id` by `referral_code` from the form data anyway, remove that filter? Why would  data passed in as that key ever be an `id`?

Comment: @IainShelvington I have a condition, I have get User on two condition, either `id` should match or `premium_referral`

Comment: @Huzzy: but the code is `XUSB5` whereas the `id` field is likely a `uuid`, it thus makes no sense to filter that way, since the format does not match.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes got it, i have editted the question u can once more check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens is because the `id` (or the `premium_referral`) is a [**`UUIDField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield). It thus does not make much sense to pass `XUSB5` as code, since that is an invalid UUID).

What you can do is check if it can be converted to a UUID and thus filter with:

```
from uuid import UUID

query = form.cleaned_data.get('referral_code')
qobj = Q(premium_referral=query)
try:
    qobj |= Q(id=UUID(query))
except ValueError:
    pass

User.objects.get(
    qobj
)
```